# JQuery droppable wont drop in div

Tags: jquery, droppable

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNe6t/) that won't drop on a droppable DIV, but will drop on a textbox not set as droppable.

Can anyone tell be why the draggable won't drop in the DIV and why it will drop in the text box?

have tried using different selectors, checked that .data('droppable') is true on the DIV (it is) and tried about everything I could find concerning issues with droppable DIVs...alas to no avail.

Comment: I can't get anything to drag in your jsFiddle.

Comment: Try selecting 'new text' first, then drag.

Comment: Well yeah, but you can do that without jQuery's draggable widget anyway.

Comment: Not sure I understand...'do what...anyway'

Comment: @user1375766 - Dragging the selected text has nothing to do with jQuery-ui's draggable plugin. That is native browser experience that allows you to drag any selected text into an input or textarea. jQuery-ui's draggable plugin is meant for dragging elements (not text) within the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time...got me pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.draggable()` directly on inputs isn't advisable as it will cause the fields to become un-editable. I would recommend wrapping your inputs in a `<span>` or `<div>` and adding `.draggable()` to those instad.

Here is your code updated as an example - http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/FNe6t/1/

Comment: Will take your advice, but doesn't solve the problem; still doesn't drop in the div

Comment: Then I must have misunderstood your question. The example I provided does allow you to grab the span surrounding the input and drop it onto the div which alerts "dropped!".

Comment: Yes, of course you are correct...I was still highlighting the text and trying to drag. Once I grabbed the span it worked. Your post in combination your comment above set me straight; was dynamically adding li items to a list but couldn't drop them anywhere as I attached draggable to 'li' on page load, not at the time of dynamically adding it...thanks